# Unable to connect Jenkins plugin to OpenStack

Tags: jenkins, openstack

How to configure OpenStack plugin to connect to OpenStack ?

I am getting :  Cannot connect to specified cloud. Please check the identity and credentials: POST http://IdentityServicesIP:5000/v2.0/tokens  HTTP/1.1 -> HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized

Answer (score 1):

The message means something is wrong with the Identity or Credential you are providing.

Check you have the project (tenant) name in front of the Identity like so:

`my project name:username`

Also, the credential must be the user's password even though the help window says it is "sometimes known as a secret key" which should not be confused with keystone ec2 credentials.

Documentation:
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Openstack+Cloud+Plugin